# Add search field result to an empty array

Tags: javascript

Every time a user types something into a search field, I want it to be added to an empty array I've created. For some reason, my current code only adds an empty string to the array but not the string itself:

Javascript

```
var myArray=[];
var submit = document.getElementById("submit");
var result = document.getElementById("result").value;

submit.addEventListener("click", function() { 
    myArray.push(result); 
})
```

HTML

```
<input id="result" type="text"><button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: You want the search string or the results of the search to be appended to the array?

Comment: the result appended to the array.